# Excel: I want to SUM the top 2 values IF a cell in the row matches a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to figure out how to SUM the top 2 values of an array using SUMPRODUCT but I also want to add a criteria that will only sum the product if it matches a specific string. I thought I could combine SUMPRODUCT and SUMIF but I have been unsuccessful.

```
Position    Age ADP Trend   Value
QB  23  241 84.2    21
QB  35  185 -37.5   142
QB  27  300 25  19
QB  26  300 25  19
QB  32  300 25  19
RB  22  98  -2.2    1051
RB  24  69  0.3 1929
RB  24  238 6   25
RB  26  300 25  19
RB  26  300 25  19
WR  22  300 25  19
WR  24  300 25  19
WR  26  232 -17 36
WR  25  300 25  19
WR  28  300 25  19
WR  23  9   -4.2    8591
WR  23  178 21.4    161
WR  23  38  8.5 4679
WR  26  222 102.8   53
WR  23  300 25  19
WR  26  300 25  19
TE  26  117 -18.7   617
TE  36  193 -30.3   119
TE  26  199 -22.5   105
TE  24  300 25  19
```

What I want is to SUM the top two values under the Value column IF the Position = QB.

How can I accomplish this?

Cheers!

Comment: I would use the IF function. Just put a conditional that uses SUMPRODUCT  if a certain cell matches your criteria. For instance: =IF(B2="STRING",SUMPRODUCT(C2:C3),)

Comment: Thank your for the assistance @RafaelMartínez . Here is what I tired: =IF(F:F="QB",SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(J:J,2))) and I get FALSE back. What am I doing wrong here? Cheers!

Comment: You are saying you will sum two value from `value` column, so why you need sumproduct?

Comment: @harun24hr i thought I needed SUMPRODUCT to use LARGE. Is that not the case? Sorry I am new to excel formulas. How do I say "I want the top  2 values summed IF they match the string"? Appreciate the help. Cheers!

Comment: @Amod see the answer. Let me know it works for you or not?

Comment: @harun24hr didn't work for me, getting #N/A when I change the ranges to what I have on my worksheet. =SUM(LARGE(IF(F:F="QB",J:J,""),1),LARGE(IF(F:F="QB",J:J,""),2)) My range has invalid values and n/a cells, would that cause a problem? Is there a way I can share my worksheet with you?

Comment: @Amod I tested the formula, so no chance to work it. Can you share a sample file so that we can check where you are doing wrong. At least put actual sheet screenshot. Do you press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` after putting formula in cell?

Answer (score 2):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(LARGE(IF(A2:A25="QB",E2:E25,""),1),LARGE(IF(A2:A25="QB",E2:E25,""),2))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

Comment: After pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` formula will looks like `{=SUM(LARGE(IF(A2:A25="QB",E2:E25,""),1),LARGE(IF(A2:A25="QB",E2:E25,""),2))}`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XJD0r-jU9dQi1ON1prdkJ3N0E/view?usp=sharing ----- the data I am trying to work is on the Wode sheet. Hope this helps! Thanks for helping me! @harun24hr

Comment: @Amod My formula is okay. Problem in your `vlookup` formula output. It is generating error in some rows, Thats why my formula do not add  values. Use `=IFERROR` formula to handle errors. I put `=IFERROR` formula to your `=VLOOKUP` formula and now it is working fine. [Download the updated file from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUqUZQzUv2tNDFFTEx6YkIwbFE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: it worked perfectly! THanks! QUestion. I thought I could make it sum the Top 3 by adding an addition LARGE section to the SUM formula making it look like =SUM(LARGE(IF(F:F="QB",J:J,""),1),LARGE(IF(F:F="QB",J:J,""),2)),LARGE(IF(F:F="QB",J:J,""),3)) but this doesn't work. What do I need to do to modify the amount that I want to sum. Thank you for all your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: @Amod If it works for you then accept my answer (Tick it as green). Use this formula to add top three value. `=SUM(LARGE(IF(F:F="QB",J:J,""),1),LARGE(IF(F:F="QB",J:J,""),2),LARGE(IF(F:F="QB",J:J,""),3))` Your bracket combination is wrong. Look carefully.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out so much. I accepted your answer ty. However when I use the formula for 3 you provided I get an error message that says Excel found a problem with the formula. It won't let me press CCTRL+SHIFT+ENTER either. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: When I am entering formula do not found any problem. See this updated file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUqUZQzUv2tVXhiY3cycFRiMnM/view?usp=sharing `I suggest you type formula from starting manually rather than copy paste. That will help you to understand the formula also no error will come`.